# execle function prototype

Tags: function, unix, exec, system-calls, variadic-functions

I have recently been studying Unix system programming. I came across this in the man page of `exec`,

`int execle(const char *path, const char *arg,..., char * const envp[]);`

How does this function prototype have a `...` in the middle ? This won't even compile !

Can someone explain this prototype please ?

I feel that this is just there for the users to see and there is a different internal implementation. This is just a guess and I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel that this is just there for the users to see

Assuming you're confused by the trailing envp[], you would be correct.  If we look at the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) documentation, we find the actual prototype should be:

```
int execle(const char *, const char *, ...);
```

And indeed, if you consult `unistd.h` on your system, you'll probably find something of that form:

```
//glibc
extern int execle (__const char *__path, __const char *__arg, ...)
    __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));

//musl
int execle(const char *, const char *, ...);

//cygwin
int     _EXFUN(execle, (const char *__path, const char *, ... ));
```

Comment: This also explains the need for the list of arguments to be terminated by a NULL pointer !